# Creating a nested JSON object

Tags: android, json, object

I am trying to create a complex nested object like this:

```
{
   "user":{
      "type":"facebook",
      "first_name":"harsha",
      "last_name":"mv",
      "gender":"male"
   },
   "friends":[
      {
         "id":"23",
         "name":"Vachana"
      },
      {
         "id":"23",
         "name":"Jyosna"
      },
      {
         "id":"23",
         "name":"Avinash"
      }
   ]
}
```

Android Java code:

```
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    try {
        user.put("first_name", "harsha");
        user.put("last_name", "mv");
        user.put("gender", "mail");

        System.out.println(user);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to nest the other objects as shown above. Can someone tell me how I can do it? What function or format do I need to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'friends' is a `JSONArray`, each of its items is a `JSONObject`. Just use put with a `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` as value. For arrays, you will have to specify the index as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a function in JSONObject

```
put(String string, Object value)
```

that takes in a JSONArray, of which you can make it an array of JSONObject's.  I'd imagine your "friend" class could generate the JSONObject that is be put into the list.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout these JSON encoding examples, so you can manage it easily through.

[JSON Encoding](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

Answer (score 1):

i am switching the subject, but insist you to use **[Gson](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)** as it maintain a all element in one class with runtime getter/setter

Answer (score 1):

Use this Json jar file its automatically set and get the values according to tagnames(Ex:firstname,lastname etc)
  download and usage of jar file get from belo link

[Android json jar file](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Gson is best suited for this, with Gson you can use regular classes of java and turn them to JSON objects , here is a sample :

```
public class Member
{    
public String  ID;
public String FirstName;    
public String LastName;    
public String Email;    
public String DisplayName ;  
public String DOB;    
public String AboutMe;   
public String MemberType;   
public String UserTypeName;

}

initiate Member class and fill in the values
Member member = new Member();
 member.ID = "1";
 .......

 //now use GSON to get the JSON

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String JSONString = gson.toJson(member);
```

for more check this http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: how is this nested?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make nested json objects then you can use following code :

```
            JSONObject objFirst = new JSONObject();
            objFirst.put("description", "ADBCD");
            objFirst.put("type", "TEXT");


            JSONObject objSecond = new JSONObject();
            objSecond.put("askjdhasjk", "XYZ");

            objFirst.accumulate("This Nw", objSecond);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Import the following
//import java.util.ArrayList;
//import org.bson.Document;

Document root= new Document();
Document rootUser = new Document();
ArrayList rootFriends= new ArrayList();
Document rootFriends0 = new Document();
Document rootFriends1 = new Document();
Document rootFriends2 = new Document();




rootUser.append("type","facebook");   
rootUser.append("first_name","harsha");
rootUser.append("last_name","mv");
rootUser.append("gender","male");
rootFriends0.append("id","23");
rootFriends0.append("name","Vachana");
rootFriends1.append("id","23");
rootFriends1.append("name","Jyosna");
rootFriends2.append("id","23");
rootFriends2.append("name","Avinash");




if (!rootUser.isEmpty()){
root.append("user",rootUser);
}
if (!rootFriends.isEmpty()){
root.append("friends",rootFriends);
}
if (!rootFriends0.isEmpty()){
rootFriends.add(rootFriends0);
}
if (!rootFriends.isEmpty()){
root.append("friends",rootFriends);
}
if (!rootFriends1.isEmpty()){
rootFriends.add(rootFriends1);
}
if (!rootFriends.isEmpty()){
root.append("friends",rootFriends);
}
if (!rootFriends2.isEmpty()){
rootFriends.add(rootFriends2);
}
if (!rootFriends.isEmpty()){
root.append("friends",rootFriends);
}


System.out.println(root.toJson());
```